# Laravel: Select2 option value

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-blade, jquery-select2

I have the following code in my view:

```
{!! Form::select(   'projectSkills', 
                    ['' => ''] + \App\Skill::where('type','freelancer')
                                ->pluck('name', 'id')
                                ->toArray(), 
                    @$skills, 
                    [
                      'class' => 'select2',
                      'multiple'=>'multiple'
                    ]
                  ) !!}
```

Where the value of the options comes as `0,1,2,3,4,5`,

I want the value as a `name` which is fetching from the table.

What am i doing wrong there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a lists consisting of: `[id => name]` by calling `pluck('name','id')`

This will be fed into the form causing a dropdown list:

```
<option value="id">name</option>
```

If you wish to change the 'value' part, you need to supply an array consisting of the correct value part.

You could do `pluck('name','name');` to get the values you want into the form.

If you look at the [the documentation of the method pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) you see that the second parameter is for the 'key' part of the array that will be returned.